# Having problems installing tensorflow (Yes I have python 3.7.9 64bit)

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I updated pip and it updated to 21.0.1. I tried "pip install tensorflow" and got:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Also tried all of these:[commands I found on other stack overflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XSkF.png)

Also this command: "pip install [https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl%22)

Got:

Collecting tensorflow==2.0.0
ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl for URL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command in cmd or terminal.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: So I tried "python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/window/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl" and got "no module named pip"

Comment: Try running: brew install python

Comment: I did that and got an error of:  "brew :The term 'brew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ brew install python
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (brew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"